# How to prove that the set difference of B in A = C

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could you please help me to do this , proof . I'm currently learning set theory and am stuck on this question.

Let A= Z , B ={ x ∈ Z : x= 2n + 5 for some n ∈ Z} and C =
{x∈ Z , x= − 2m for some m ∈ Z} . Prove that A \ B =  C.

Comment: Notice that $B$ is the set of all odd integers while $C$ is the set of all even integers.

Comment: i saw that , but dismissed it , because it didnt match the definition of odd and eben that i learned , namely 2n+1 and m . n element of N... thank you ... i dont know how , but i think i can figure it out .

Answer (score 0):

$x\in A\setminus B\iff x\in A, x\notin B$

$\iff x\in \mathbb{Z},$  and $ x\neq 2n+5, \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$

$\iff x\in \mathbb{Z},$  and $ x\neq 2(n+1)+1, \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$

$\iff x\in \mathbb{Z},$  and $ x= 2a, \exists a\in \mathbb{Z}$

$\iff x\in \mathbb{Z},$  and $ x= -2m, \exists m\in \mathbb{Z}$

$\iff x\in C$